# How to fix runtime error related to copying vba array into word doc table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am currently trying to copy an array into a table in a word doc, but I keep getting runtime error 5948 ("The requested member of the collection does not exist.") on the first call of `doc.Tables(1).Columns(i).Cells(f).Select` and I am unsure of how to solve this. The loop which is supposed to write into the word table fails on i = 0.

EDIT: Added in the full code as well as a screenshot of my table.

```
Sub makeReport(lNum As Long, pDay As Date, name As String)
    'Template Path: \\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports\Template\Defect Report.dotm
    'Save path for finished report: \\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports
    
    'Initialize word objects and open word
    Dim obj As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim wdCell As Word.Cell
    
    'MsgBox ("Word Doc Opened")
    
    Set obj = New Word.Application
    obj.Visible = True
    Set doc = obj.Documents.Add(Template:=("\\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports\Template\Defect Report.dotm"), NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
    doc.SaveAs2 Filename:="\\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports\" + name, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    
    
    'MsgBox ("Word Objects Initialized")
    
    'Fill in lot number and date at top of report
    With doc
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<date>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Format(pDay, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<lot>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = lNum
    End With
    
    'MsgBox ("Filled in pack date and lot number")
    
    'Initialize excel objects
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim wFunc As WorksheetFunction
    
    Set wFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set wBook = ThisWorkbook
    
    Worksheets("Defect Table").Activate
    Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    
    'MsgBox ("Set Active Sheet to Defect Table")
    
    'Initialize copy control variables
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    
    x = Selection.Rows.count
    
    'MsgBox ("Number of rows: " + CStr(x))
    
    Dim numArray() As Long
    Dim dateArray() As Date
    Dim hold(0 To 7) As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim msg As String
    Dim c As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim e As Long
    Dim f As Long
    Dim g As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim sample(0 To 29) As Variant
    
    i = 0
    ReDim numArray(2 To x)
    ReDim dateArray(2 To x)
    
    For y = 2 To x
        'Array which holds all lot numbers
        numArray(y) = CInt(Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 3).Value)
        
        'Array which holds all dates
        dateArray(y) = CDate(Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 1).Value)
        
        If (lNum = numArray(y) And pDay = dateArray(y)) Then
            hold(i) = y
            i = i + 1
        End If
        
    Next y
    
    msg = "Appropriate samples found." + vbCrLf + "Rows: "
    
    For i = 0 To 7
        msg = msg + vbCrLf + CStr(hold(i))
    Next i
    
    MsgBox (msg)
    
    'Copies samples over to word doc
    For i = 0 To 7
        
        d = hold(i)
        
        If d = 0 Then
            b = i
            Exit For
        End If
        
        For c = 4 To 32
            e = c - 4
            
            If e = 30 Then
                e = e + 1
                c = c + 1
            End If
            
            sample(e) = ActiveSheet.Cells(d, c).Value
            
            g = 1
            
            For f = 0 To 32
                
                Select Case f 'Accounts for blanks left in lines 6, 10, 16, 22, 30 of table in word doc
                    
                    Case 0, 6, 10, 16, 22, 30
                        g = f + 1
                    
                    Case Else
                        g = f
                
                End Select
                
                doc.Tables(1).Columns(i + 1).Cells(g).Select
                obj.Selection.TypeText (sample(f))
                
                f = f + 1
                g = g + 1
            Next f
        Next c
        
        If i = b Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    '---MsgBox ("Data copied to Word Doc")
    
    'Saves Document using regular name format for ease of access
    '---doc.SaveAs2 Filename:="\\CORE\Miscellaneous\Quality\Sample Reports\" + name, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    
    'Zeroes out word/excel objects
    '---Set doc = Nothing
    '---Set obj = Nothing
    '---Set wBook = Nothing
    
    '---MsgBox ("Report saved and objects zeroed out")
End Sub
```

[image: Table I copy data into.]

Comment: I highly doubt `0` is a valid index for `Cells`.

Comment: `f = f + 1` - it's normally bad practice to modify the counter within the loop.

Comment: and what is `g` doing?

Comment: I have a few blank rows in the word table for formatting reasons; do you have a better means of accounting for this as I add the data. The word table is a built in part of the template I load the doc from.

Comment: Add the blank lines after you have populated the table.  Alternatively, make the row depth of the affected rows deeper so that the spacing is still there but you are only using one row, not two.

Comment: Please do not abandon previous questions after people have taken the trouble to respond there, only to post another question with basically the same issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617987/how-to-resolve-runtime-errors-copying-from-excel-to-word   If you're not willing to engage here folks will stop trying to help.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback on population of the table, but the main issue I was looking to solve was the fact I get a runtime error on `doc.Tables(1).Columns(i).Cells(g).Select` which says that "The requested member of the collection does not exist." I would really appreciate some help with that problem.

Comment: I posted a new question because I had significantly changed my approach and felt that this deserved a new page. I guess I was wrong in that regard.

Comment: As in your previous post, the error is telling you there either no column with (1-based) index `i` or if there is such a column there's no cell in that column with index `g`.  It would help to show the entire code, including the loop for `i`.  And a screenshot of your table would be useful.  FYI you do not need to select anything here:  `doc.Tables(1).Columns(i).Cells(g).Range.Text = sample(f)` will do what you want.